# Register UDF dynamically in spark using scala reflection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, user-defined-functions, scala-reflect

**Problem:**
My program accepts a JSON string as inpu, which contains a udf name, function definition and type. eg.

```
{
  "udfList": [
   {
     "name": "add"
     "definition": "(x: Int, y:int) => x+y"
     "type": "(Int, Int) => Int"
   }
  ]
}
```

The JSON can contain any function and type. How can i use scala reflection to convert this string to actual function and cast to the given type then register it as udf with the give name.

**Tried:**

```
val myFunc = """(x: Int, y:int) => x+y"""
val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val tree = tb.parse(myFunc)
val fun =  tb.eval(tree)
```

I am not able to cast it dynamically because the type is passed as String. So is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Maybe a dynamic Java compiler like Janino (https://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/) be a better choice than custom text parsing and reflection. Especially since Spark itself already uses Janino.